# Replace different html-text with javascript for translating page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a multilingual WordPress website with a field that is generated with `ACF-Field`. `WPML` is not able to translate it (2nd-level-support is working on it). So I was thinking to let JavaScript translate the different Text-Fields, but I can not manage it.

What I would like to do:

if the url-slug contains `/fr` then
translate
Präsident into président
Berater into consultant
Sekretär into secrétaire

if the url-slug contains `/it` then
translate
Präsident into presidente
Berater into 
consulente
Sekretär into secretario

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

I already got some results but only for one text-variable

```
var src_str = ("Präsident");
var str_repFRp = src_str.replace("Präsident","président");

$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$isItFrench = strpos($url, '/fr');

if ($isItFrench!==false)
{
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = str_repFRp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WPML fully supports any ACF field.

Remember that an ACF field is nothing but a custom Wordpress field, therefore it is possible to translate it via WPML

Read WPML Documentation: https://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/translate-sites-built-with-acf/